# Record video to memory in Java

Tags: java, opencv, video, record, outputstream

I am using OpenCV 3.1.0 in Java to record video segments, and then upload those segments to a site. By using the VideoWriter class, I have to save each video segment to a file, but was hoping to instead save each video segment to an output stream. This would effectively reduce the IO cost by saving the video to main memory.

I am able to successfully write and read a sequence of mats to a byte array (which avoids file IO). However, this methodology doesn't allow me to use modern compression techniques (like MJPEG) to reduce the size of the files saved to the site.

Does anyone know how to record video (using MJPEG or some other encoding) to memory rather than to a file or URL?

Comment: Maybe post the code you have so far?